# Скопировать данные из datagridview в datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

Я создал колонки в гриде, вручную добавил строки туда же.

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(...)
```

Теперь хочу привязать данные из `datagridview` в `datatable`, но у `datagridview.datasource` показывает null.. Хотя данные в гриде есть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы хотите "слить данные" из `GridView` в таблицу или что?
`Null` в `datasource`, потому как в качестве источника ничего не было изначально указано.
 По клику кнопки в обработчике:

1. Создаете `DataTable` и формируете структуру как в гриде.
2. Пробегаетесь по всем столбцам в `GridView` и записываете данные колонок во вновь
   сформированную `DataTable`.
3. Сохраняете `DataTable`.
4. Прицепляется GridView.DataSource= DataTable; GridView.Bind();

Хотя вроде как все наоборот делают :)